# list all 3 to 5 author names in the first in-text citation using apacite

Tags: formatting, apa-style

I use `\usepackage{apacite}` in the preamble (sublime 2 editor) and `\bibliographystyle{apacite}`. I did not have to manually install the apacite package. For in-text citations of 3 to 5 authors, I need to have all authors listed in the first occurrence and then the first author et al., in subsequent occurrences.  But with the above commands, it is always first author et al. in all occurrences. How could I force it to do the necessary?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the command you use to cite. Following the [apacite documentation at CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apacite/apacite.pdf), plain `\cite` command does what you say. Check carefully section 4, *The citation commands*. There are `\fullcite` and `\shortcite` commands to force a full list or a short list of authors, but they should only be necessary on rare cases because first/second citations of 3-to-5 authors should behave well automatically unless another commands or packages are interferring. Besides, often recommended biblatex and biblatex-apa solutions are known to work, see the [test document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-apa/biblatex-apa-test.pdf) at CTAN.